# if specific value/string occurs in the entire dataframe I want to sum its index values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe in which I need to find a specific image name in the entire dataframe and sum its index values every time they are found. SO my data frame looks like:

```
c            1                 2           3                    4    
g                   
0    180731-1-61.jpg    180731-1-61.jpg   180731-1-61.jpg   180731-1-61.jpg     
1   1209270004-2.jpg    180609-2-31.jpg   1209270004-2.jpg  1209270004-2.jpg    
2   1209270004-1.jpg    180414-2-38.jpg   180707-1-31.jpg   1209050002-1.jpg    
3   1708260004-1.jpg    1209270004-2.jpg  180609-2-31.jpg   1209270004-1.jpg    
4   1108220001-5.jpg    1209270004-1.jpg  1108220001-5.jpg  1108220001-2.jpg
```

I need to find the `1209270004-2.jpg` in entire dataframe. And as it is found at index `1` and `3` I want to add the index values so it should be
`1+3+1+1=6`. 
I tried the code:

```
img_fname = '1209270004-2.jpg'
df2 = df1[df1.eq(img_fname).any(1)]
sum = int(np.sum(df2.index.values))
print(sum)
```

I am getting the answer of sum `4` i.e 1+3=4. But it should be `6`.
If the string occurence is only once or twice or thrice or four times like for eg `180707-1-31` is in column 3. then the sum should be `45+45+3+45 = 138`. Which signifies that if the string is not present in the dataframe take vallue as 45 instead the index value.

Comment: I have idea - can you copy data to new DataFrame and add `45` values for `45+45+3+45 ` ?

Comment: Can we check the number of occurence of the string in dataframe. Max is 5 and min is 0.

Comment: if the string is not present in each column make that index value 45, here 45 is just a constant value adding to it.

Comment: How is processing second row?

Comment: It should check according to the columns if its not present in the columns then by default it should take the value 45 instead of 0.

Comment: suppose for `1209270004-1.jpg` (see in the dataframe provided) it matches in column 1 at index 2 so `2`, it matches at column 2 at index 4 so `4`, its not matching at column 3 so `45` and it matches at column 4 at index 3 so `3`. So `2+4+45+3`.

Comment: understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiple boolean mask by index values and then `sum`:

```
img_fname = '1209270004-1.jpg'
s = df1.eq(img_fname).mul(df1.index.to_series(), 0).sum()
print (s)
1    2
2    4
3    0
4    3
dtype: int64

out = np.where(s == 0, 45, s).sum()
print (out)
54
```

Comment: your solution is correct but its creating problems with my previous code. I'll edit in my question.

Answer (score 1):

If dataset does not have many columns, this can also work with your original question

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["aa","ab", "cd", "ab", "aa"], "B":["ab","ab", "ab", "aa", "ab"]})
s = 0    
for i in df1.columns:
    s= s+ sum(df1.index[df1.loc[:,i] == "ab"].tolist())
```

Input :

```
    A   B
0   aa  ab
1   ab  ab
2   cd  ab
3   ab  aa
4   aa  ab
```

Output :11

[image]

Based on second requirement:

[image]

Comment: @KrupaliMistry It works fine with the dataset I used. It would be great if you can provide the dataset sample code you are working on.

Regarding your requirement, just place the index in the each value if it is equivalent to that string otherwise place 45 , and sum up all the values of dataframe

Comment: I tried your same code, taking the dataframe same, still it gives me the same error.

Comment: I did not modify anything, still not getting the error; updated my post with screenshot. I am using python 3, which version are you using?

Comment: python 3.7 but with jupyter notebook

Comment: I got it the first one but what about 45?

Comment: I am also using jupyter notebook with python 3.7. I am surprised why is it giving error to you.
Did you paste exact code or did you change "s" to "sum"? The root cause of the error you see might be -- you are defining any variable with function name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198288/discussion-between-krupali-mistry-and-akanksha).